# How to create OWL document

Tags: rdf, jena, semantic-web, owl

I have downloaded an OWL file from the web and I need to know how it has been written using Jena. I can write plain RDF documents, but I cannot understand to write OWL documents.
OWL file content is below.

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">

    <!-- OWL Header Example -->
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.linkeddatatools.com/plants">
        <dc:title>The LinkedDataTools.com Example Plant Ontology</dc:title>
        <dc:description>An example ontology written for the LinkedDataTools.com RDFS & OWL introduction tutorial</dc:description>
    </owl:Ontology>

    <!-- OWL Class Definition Example -->
    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.linkeddatatools.com/plants#planttype">
        <rdfs:label>The plant type</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:comment>The class of plant types.</rdfs:comment>
        <rdfs:description> Plant type description </rdfs:description>
    </owl:Class>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no difference. An OWL ontology encoded in RDF is just another RDF document - there's nothing special about the OWL syntax as far as Jena is concerned. What matters in an RDF document is what triples it contains: that's why you can have RDF encoded in XML, Turtle or N-triples and they're all equivalent - just different ways of writing down the same triples.

Once an RDF tool has loaded the triples into a graph (i.e. a `Model` in Jena), then it can give a different interpretation to terms from the `owl:` namespace.

**Update**

OK, following request in the comment here is code that generates your output sample:

```java
package example;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.*;

public class OWLOutputExample
{
    public static final String PLANTS = "http://www.linkeddatatools.com/plants";

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        new OWLOutputExample().run();
    }

    public void run() {
        OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM );

        setNamespaces( m );
        populateOntology( m );
        writeOntology( m );
    }

    private void setNamespaces( OntModel m ) {
        m.setNsPrefix( "owl", OWL.getURI() );
        m.setNsPrefix( "rdf", RDF.getURI() );
        m.setNsPrefix( "rdfs", RDFS.getURI() );
        m.setNsPrefix( "dc", DC_11.getURI() );
        m.setNsPrefix( "plants", PLANTS );
    }

    private void populateOntology( OntModel m ) {
        Ontology ont = m.createOntology( PLANTS );
        ont.addProperty( DC_11.title, "The LinkedDataTools.com Example Plant Ontology" )
           .addProperty( DC_11.description, "An example ontology written for the " +
                                               "LinkedDataTools.com RDFS & OWL introduction tutorial" );

        OntClass plantType = m.createClass( PLANTS + "#planttype" );
        plantType.addProperty( RDFS.label, "The plant type" )
                 .addProperty( RDFS.comment, "The class of plant types." );
    }

    private void writeOntology( OntModel m ) {
        m.write( System.out, "RDF/XML-ABBREV" );
    }
}
```

Output:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:plants="http://www.linkeddatatools.com/plants"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.linkeddatatools.com/plants">
    <dc:description>An example ontology written for the LinkedDataTools.com RDFS &amp; OWL introduction tutorial</dc:description>
    <dc:title>The LinkedDataTools.com Example Plant Ontology</dc:title>
  </owl:Ontology>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.linkeddatatools.com/plants#planttype">
    <rdfs:comment>The class of plant types.</rdfs:comment>
    <rdfs:label>The plant type</rdfs:label>
  </owl:Class>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Note that `rdfs:description` is not a known RDFS property, so I left it out.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, But what I want to know is how to write above OWL document in Jena, Can you please give me the code to produce that OWL document.

Comment: Fantastic!!!! Thank you very much. This is exactly I wanted to know.

If you don't mind,I have another question for you. I want to use this OWL document and dynamically add sub classes for the classes I have in this OWL document? Can you suggest me a good way for this?

Comment: @user360321 That's really a separate question. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18804302/1281433) has some examples of adding subclasses, though.